# Formatting values and put them instead of old ones

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function in a Node service

```
  pendingBetsForCustomer: function(params) {
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      var cancel, view, fillOpen,
      connection = new sql.Connection(sails.config.connections.myConnection, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        var request = connection.request();
        decorateRequestParams(request, params);
        request.execute('[SP_NAME].[spREPORTS]', function(err, dataset) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          _.map(dataset, function(items) {
            return _.map(items, function(item) {

              cancel = item.XX_CANCEL;         
              fillOpen = item.XX_FILL_OPEN;

              parseString(cancel, function(err, res) {
                cancel = res;
              });
              parseString(fillOpen, function(err, res) {
                fillOpen = res;
              });
            });
          });

          _.forEach(dataset, function(report) {
            console.log(report); //see below what it returns
            fullfill(report);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

In the `console.log(report)` I get something like this

```
[ { BET: 57630343,
    CUSTOMER: 181645,
    SPORT: 'MLB',
    XX_FILL_OPEN: '<xxfillopen xml>...</xxfillopen xml>',
    XX_CANCEL: '<xxcancel xml>...</xxcancel xml>' },
   ...
]
```

those props starting with `XX_` are XML elements that I need to turn into JSON, which you can see above (using xml2js) as

```
      _.map(dataset, function(items) {
        return _.map(items, function(item) {

          cancel = item.XX_CANCEL;
          fillOpen = item.XX_FILL_OPEN;

          parseString(cancel, function(err, res) {
            cancel = res;
          });
          parseString(fillOpen, function(err, res) {
            fillOpen = res;
          });
        });
      });
```

if you see above, I have `cancel` and `fillOpen` which now are json instead of XML, all I need is to put `cancel` instead of `XX_CANCEL: '<xxcancel xml>...</xxcancel xml>`

thinking that cancel is the object with the json format and the same with Fill Open, like this:

`{XX_CANCEL: cancel}`

I am expecting something like this

```
[ {
    BET: 57630343,
    CUSTOMER: 181645,
    SPORT: 'MLB',
    XX_FILL_OPEN: //PUT HERE THE NEW ATTR IN JSON FORMAT,
    XX_CANCEL: //PUT HERE THE NEW ATTR IN JSON FORMAT
   },...
]
```

OK, so now, I have those props starting with `XX_` formatted, so what should I do to put those new formatted props as json instead of the old ones in XML format?

Comment: I'm probably not interpreting your question correctly, but are you expecting `dataset` to be something different after the `_.map(dataset)` than before?  As your code stands, your `_.map(dataset..)` will have no effect at all on `_.forEach(dataset,..)` because you're not altering `dataset`, just returning a new array that you're ignoring because you're not assigning the mapped value to anything.

Comment: @caasjj yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out; how to replace those XML elements in dataset and put the new ones from _.map(dataset...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your map function:

```
      _.map(dataset, function(items) {
        return _.map(items, function(item) {

          parseString(item.XX_CANCEL, function(err, res) {
            item.XX_CANCEL = res;
          });
          parseString(item.XX_FILL_OPEN, function(err, res) {
            item.XX_FILL_OPEN = res;
          });
        });
      });
```

this should replace the xml strings with the parsed JSON data.

Comment: how do I assign those values to dataset in order to replace the old ones?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer The above code already replaces the values. The `_.forEach` code should be seeing the replaced values. Unless `parseString` is asynchronous?

Comment: @tcocc - `parseString` is asynchronous.  When do you propose to resolve or reject the promise?

Comment: I am doing it like this `parseString(item.XX_CANCEL, function(err, res) {if(err) {reject(err); item.XX_CANCEL = res;});` is there something wrong?

Comment: hmmm .. and when do you resolve the promise?  this looks like a very dubious async code pattern to me - the kind that could bite you unexpectedly.

Comment: sorry, I am very new to node and JS in general. I was reading about promises but then how do I resolve it ? could give me a code sample ?